# how to pass directives to dcc32 via msbuild?

Tags: delphi

In Delphi XE3 if I compile from the command line, how can I pass additional directives to the invoked dcc32.exe?

This is my workflow:

1. open a command prompt
2. call xe3\bin\rsvars.bat
3. cd to my project folder
4. msbuild.exe /target:Clean,Build /property:Config=Release;Platform=Win32 /verbosity:normal "C:\proj_xyz\xyz.dproj"

Everything compiles fine except that I need to generate a detailed map file.
Please note that compiling from the IDE does produce the map file.

How can I add to the generated dcc32 command the -GD switch to force the creation of the map file?

thanks

---

## Edit:

Thanks to the answers I've received I further investigated: the problem was that I was building with Release config.
Switching to Debug config and enabling in it the detailed map file generation in the IDE, produced the desired effect.
I've studied the changed .dproj file and discovered that a new property DCC_MapFile=3 was added to it.
At this point I've disabled again in the ide the map file generation and added to the msbuild command line this property:

/property:DCC_MapFile=3

so this was the answer to my question (how can I pass a parameter to msbuid to be passed to dcc32.exe ;-)

Comment: So your RELEASE profile in the IDE has MAP on, or the DEBUG profile has MAP on? Your results tend to suggest switching to RELEASE has resulted in use of Release mode settings where MAP will then be OFF. :-) Ergo, turn on MAP flag in link settings for RELEASE mode. And done.

Comment: Change the setting in the .dproj file